# Need Advice on Multithreaded Merge Sort

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, sorting

Basically, if the number of lists in a merge sort is equal to the number of cores in the computer it will spawn a thread to sort each of the lists. It works currently but the problem that I'm facing is that it's actually taking longer to sort than the normal merge sort. It takes longer because instead of spawning lets say 4 threads at the same time, it's spawning a thread and it goes through its whole process before moving on to calling the next thread. Below is the code that I wrote, it works but again it goes slower because of the problem I stated above. If anyone has any familiarity with using threads in sorting algorithms any feedback would be greatly appreciated. FURTHERMORE, this is not homework, my project for class was to design a normal merge sort, I'm just trying to experiment around with the language and try different things.

```
void MergeSortThreading(int low, int high, int* source, int* destination, int count)
{
if (low == high)
    return;
int mid = (low + high) / 2;
int start_1 = low, end_1 = mid, start_2 = (mid + 1), end_2 = high, dest = start_1;

if (pow(2, count) == cores())
{
    thread* processes = new thread[cores()];
    int j = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < cores(); i++)
    {
        processes[i] = thread(MergeSortThreading, j, (j + (high)), destination, source, 1000);
        j += (high - 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cores(); i++)
        processes[i].join();
}

MergeSortThreading(low, mid, destination, source, ++count);
MergeSortThreading((mid + 1), high, destination, source, 150);

while (start_1 <= end_1 && start_2 <= end_2)
{
    if (source[start_1] > source[start_2])
        destination[dest++] = source[start_2++];
    else
        destination[dest++] = source[start_1++];
}

if (start_1 > end_1)
{
    for (; start_2 <= end_2; start_2++)
    {
        destination[dest] = source[start_2];
        dest++;
    }
}
else
{
    for (; start_1 <= end_1; start_1++)
    {
        destination[dest] = source[start_1];
        dest++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Aside: don't use `pow` when you need to do exact calculation.

Comment: Another aside: don't use `new` when you can use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: what does `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` do exactly? I'm very new to programming in c++. Also, @Hurkyl can you please elaborate on what you mean by not using the pow function?

Comment: Your launching code looks correct. We can't evaluate your implementation since you don't provide any details of it (or even the details of your own evaluation). However, I can point out that doing a parallel merge in any useful manner is a nontrivial problem. (although that only affects the cost of the last and largest merges, and isn't a prerequisite to get any advantage out of parallelism)

Comment: @Feek: `pow` does floating point calculations, and floating point calculations aren't guaranteed to give exactly the right answer. You'll get in trouble if it returns `15.9999` when you were expecting `16`. For powers of 2, the usual method is `(1 << count)`. `*_ptr` are smart pointers, and should be preferred to `new` in the majority of circumstances, since they do appropriate cleanup automatically; google them, they're a standard topic. However, in this circumstance, using `std::vector` would be even more preferable. (along with its `emplace_back` method)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback. I have also edited my code to include details of my implementation. Again though, it looks right to me but the error I'm having is that the normal merge sort takes about 10 seconds to sort 20-million pieces of data but when I try to run this on 20-million pieces of data it takes around 19 seconds, when it should be faster.

Comment: The question is better asked at SE Code Review.

Comment: I can't completely follow your design (e.g. I haven't figured out what `count` is supposed to be doing), but it looks like after you have done several mergesorts in parallel, you completely ignore that fact and continue on to do the single-threaded recursion.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding how to use threads, but the count variable is for figuring out the depth of the tree. For example, when count hits 2 I know that there are 4 lists (2 ^ 2) so I make a separate thread for each of the four lists. After spawning threads for each of the lists the count variable is rendered useless because I won't have to make any more threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple method to parallelize a recursion that splits into two at each step is with the following structure:

```
void recursive_function(int threads_to_use)
{
    if(threads_to_use == 1) {
        recursive_function(1);
        recursive_function(1);
    } else {
        int half = threads_to_use / 2;
        thread th(recursive_function, half);
        recursive_function(threads_to_use - half);
        th.join();
    }
}
```

It's not the ideal solution, but it is a decent one and relatively easy to tack onto an existing single-threaded design if the two calls can be done concurrently.

It might be better to use `std::async` to do asynchronous function calls rather than doing low-level thread creation if your C++ library provided a good implementation of it... but the ones I've used haven't really been all that useful (either creating too many threads or not doing multi-threading at all), so I can't really advise trying to learn to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering that with 20 million integers to sort, the main pacing issue is main memory bandwidth, and even with multiple cores, each with a local level 1 and level 2 cache isn't going to help much, since the merge sort will involve a lot of sequential reads or writes to main memory, which I'm thinking is the bottle neck here.

I'm also wondering if having 4 cores doing a merge sort at the same time is going to reduce the the percentage of sequential read and writes to main memory, slowing the process down.

I ran both a top down and a bottom up merge sort on 20 million (20*1024*1024) 32 bit integers, and both take about 2 seconds on my system (Intel 2600K, 3.4ghz). Almost all the time is spent in the merge runs function, which seems only slightly better than the example in the question, but here's the code in case this might help. Note that a[] is the original array, and b[] is the temp array.

```
int * TopDownMergeSort(int a[], int b[], size_t n)
{
    if(n < 2)                           // if size < 2 return
        return a;
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(a, b, 0, n);
    return a;
}

void TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(int a[], int b[], size_t ll, size_t ee)
{
    if((ee - ll) == 1)                  // if size == 1 return
        return;
    size_t rr = (ll + ee)>>1;           // midpoint, start of right half
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(a, b, ll, rr);
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(a, b, rr, ee);
    MergeRuns(b, a, ll, rr, ee);        // merge b to a
}

void TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(int a[], int b[], size_t ll, size_t ee)
{
    if((ee - ll) == 1){                 // if size == 1 copy a to b
        b[ll] = a[ll];
        return;
    }
    size_t rr = (ll + ee)>>1;           // midpoint, start of right half
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(a, b, ll, rr);
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(a, b, rr, ee);
    MergeRuns(a, b, ll, rr, ee);        // merge a to b
}

void MergeRuns(int a[], int b[], size_t ll, size_t rr, size_t ee)
{
    size_t o = ll;                      // b[]       index
    size_t l = ll;                      // a[] left  index
    size_t r = rr;                      // a[] right index
    while(1){                           // merge data
        if(a[l] <= a[r]){               // if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o++] = a[l++];            //   copy a[l]
            if(l < rr)                  //   if not end of left run
                continue;               //     continue (back to while)
            while(r < ee)               //   else copy rest of right run
                b[o++] = a[r++];
            break;                      //     and return
        } else {                        // else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o++] = a[r++];            //   copy a[r]
            if(r < ee)                  //   if not end of right run
                continue;               //     continue (back to while)
            while(l < rr)               //   else copy rest of left run
                b[o++] = a[l++];
            break;                      //     and return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `MergeRuns` is the only part doing anything, so it shouldn't be surprising that's where it spends most of its time. I think around half the merge work will probably be on datasets that fit in L1 cache, which will benefit from parallelism (and will parallelize easily).

Comment: @Hurkyl - Once sufficiently optimized, merge sort is mostly limited by main memory bandwidth, and memory bandwidth will limit how fast the caches can be filled or emptied, regardless how many caches are used in parallel. Changing to a higher order merge sort, like a 4 way merge sort, would cut the number of passes in half, but I'm not sure if using multiple cores in this case would help either. Having multiple memory busses, like on some server motherboards, would help.

Comment: If you can sort an entire L1-sized block of data faster than it takes to fill the cache, then yes you'll be bandwidth limited; IIRC, my experience is that that's not the case, and the bottom half of the recursion is not bandwidth limited. A well-optimized sort could hide that in various ways (and as you point out, could can trade compute for bandwidth at the top of the recursion too), but it was not my intention to get into more advanced ways to optimize a sort here.

Comment: At 8k elements, both arrays fit in L1; everything is a cache hit, so main memory isn't involved at all throughout those 13 passes, except for the equivalent of one pass through the data.

Comment: @Hurkyl - good point. However, unlike a top down merge sort, in this case, a bottom up merge sort moves 80MB of data on every pass, and yet it's about 5 percent faster (1.9 seconds versus 2.0 seconds) than top down sort. Top down generates the indices via recursion, making (n-1) calls (1 + 2 + 4 + ... + (n/2) = n-1), while bottom up skips the recursion and generates the indices via iteration. So whatever advantage top down merge sort has for locality during the first 13 passes is lost due to recursive generation of indices.